# Ruby on Rails with Github Pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, deployment, github-pages

I am attempting to host a project using Github pages. As I understand it, Ruby on Rails cannot be run on GH-Pages, with the exception of using Jekyll. My project is not a blog, and therefor Jekyll seems like overkill. Is there any other way to deploy to GH-Pages? Is there another way to generate a static site from my Ruby on Rails app that would allow for easier deployment?

Thanks for any and all input.

Comment: While Jekyll is blog-aware, it works equally well for static sites and not in any way overkill.

Comment: I agree with @BartJedrocha I'm using Jekyll on Github Pages and as a total beginner have had only a few minor hiccups. I've yet to code the blog part posts section of the website. The reason being I'm not writing them I'm converting them from Stack Exchange Answers I've written.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm afraid not. Rails is a dynamic system, meaning that the pages are generated from templates combined with data. GH-pages only servers static HTML, so even if you put static content into Rails, you would not be able to run the scripts that serve it.

Use Jekyll or [Middleman](https://middlemanapp.com/) to make a static site. If you really need Rails, use [Heroku's free plan](https://www.heroku.com/).

Comment: Hm. That's what I suspected. Thanks for the fast reply, Matt.

Comment: Hello, Matt Gibson

I have question related to this. Is there Jekyll like too that allow me to develop website with full stack like rails in local area and deploy it in static format?

Comment: @Batbayar There are several tools you could use (Jekyll being one of them), but it's more the approach that matters as this is not what they are naturally good at. Check out the JAMstack site for details https://jamstack.org/

Answer (score 0):

You could use [actionpack-page_caching](https://github.com/rails/actionpack-page_caching) to generate page-level caches in the `public` folder of your Rails application, then add those generated pages to your `GitHub Pages` repository.

However, this entirely defeats the purpose of using something like Rails. Why don't you just create static pages directly and upload those to your GitHub Pages repo?

Comment: Thanks Jon; just saw this one now. Will be looking into it.